# How to create sublist based on condition in Java

Tags: java

I have a list of `String`

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("C", "C++", "Java"));
```

And now I want to create another list, which would contain all elements of `strings` that contain `"C"`. So I believe that the condition would look like this:

```
(String a) -> a.contains("C");
```

What is the fastest and most clear way to do that?

Comment: `strings.stream().filter(t -> t.contains("C")).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Another possibility:  `strings.removeIf(a -> !a.contains("C"))` (Note that this modifies the `strings` List itself.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend *streaming* the `List` and then using [`Stream#filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) to filter through any elements that contain the letter `'C'`:

```
List<String> filteredList = strings.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.contains("C"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Printing `filteredList` will yield the following:

```
[C, C++]
```